# Edit grace period

Tags: discussion, editing

I think the grace period limit of 5 minutes that merges edit events is too long.

It is adequate for a site like Stack Overflow, but not for a Code Golf site, as edits are more frequent and each edit has more significance.

What do you think?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the grace period is actually a problem?

Comment: I had always wished for a *longer* grace period.

Comment: Are you talking about for challenges or for answers (or both)?

Comment: @xnor: At least for answers. For questions is not so relevant.

Comment: @MartinEnder I would like at least the option to have "Do not merge with previous" on edits to manage better what was the evolution on which update. If I see several merged updates on only one edit, I lose the context of what I did on each one.

Comment: @sergiol I understand your complaint now from your comments, whereas I didn't from the post. I'd suggest expanding more on why the five minute grace period is a problem

Comment: @sergiol post that opinion [on "Do not merge with previous"] as an answer to this question, see what the community thinks. I think that would be an excellent option.

Comment: Occasionally golfs in quick succession don't get saved, with annoying consequences.

Comment: I think this goes against what I've always thought was save an edit until you have a good amount of golfing to do and do it at once. So there would usually be a larger time between making edits anyway, especially when you have to format the post, update an explanation, get the new TIO link etc.